# ruptimed: getaddrinfo error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I'm doing a test on ruptimed.c in chapter 15 of book APUE. My computer is Mac(Catalina 10.15.4)

```
struct addrinfo *ailist, *aip;
    struct addrinfo hint;
    int             sockfd, err, n;
    char            *host;

    if (argc != 1)
        err_quit("usage: ruptimed");
    if ((n = sysconf(_SC_HOST_NAME_MAX)) < 0)
        n = HOST_NAME_MAX;  /* best guess */
    if ((host = malloc(n)) == NULL)
        err_sys("malloc error");
    if (gethostname(host, n) < 0)
        err_sys("gethostname error");
    daemonize("ruptimed");
    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
    hint.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hint.ai_addr = NULL;
    hint.ai_next = NULL;
    if ((err = getaddrinfo(host, "ruptime", &hint, &ailist)) != 0) { /* getaddrinfo error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known */
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "host: %s", host);
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "ruptimed: getaddrinfo error: %s",
          gai_strerror(err));
        exit(1);
    }
```

syslog :
`Jul 20 10:17:25 yuanzhongmingdeMacBook-Pro ruptimed[26675] <Error>: host: yuanzhongmingdeMacBook-Pro.local Jul 20 10:17:25 yuanzhongmingdeMacBook-Pro ruptimed[26675] <Error>: ruptimed: getaddrinfo error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

and /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1 yuanzhongmingdeMacBook-Pro.local
```

I have searched on google, it's probably the DNS problem. And I ping the host to make sure it's reachable.
I've closed my proxy (Shadowsocks), but it still does't work.

Comment: Have you considered that it may be the service name, not the host name, that is unknown to `getaddrinfo`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, many thanks.I have checked the related question. It seems the service 'ruptime'  is not registered in /etc/services. But I think it's a little confusing.